# Magento 2 Add Custom tab in Product Page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, tabs, product-details

I like to view my product page information details like "accordion-toggle" and let me need to add **custom tab** with static text in same page information details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create below file in this location

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="product/view/custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Cutom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Go to this link

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom_tab.phtml

```
<?php echo __("test")?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got a custom tab. I like to change tab design to toogle design, is there any idea to change ?

Comment: @mohana which type you want to change in tab?

Comment: Done. 1st all tab must be close onclick open drop down. please refer the link "https://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/pen/JroaYK" .

Comment: @mohana you can customize in product page default tab remove and manally add after get all attributes

Comment: Please can you send some reference link.?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, i had a small confuse to add multi custom tab. Now I added 3 custom tab, but now displaying only i created last tab and default tab. My 1st two custom tab is not showing.